# Is there a way to extend the lifetime of locally defined variables?

Tags: rust

Use case: I've got a paginated Graphql API where many different entities return an opaque cursor and a boolean `hasNext`. I would like to make these entities available as a `TryStream` to allow computations to happen while all pages are being fetched.

I've defined a trait to abstract that. `get_data` fetches a single page:

```
trait PaginatedEntityQuery {
    type ResponseData;
    fn get_cursor(data: &Self::ResponseData) -> Option<String>;
    fn has_next_page(data: &Self::ResponseData) -> bool;
    fn get_data<'a>(
        &self, // access to query variables
        backend: &'a Backend,  // access to a backend to get data from
        cursor: Option<String>,  // the cursor in the pagination
    ) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::ResponseData>> + 'a>>;
}
```

I'm using `try_unfold` in my Backend `impl`:

```
fn get_paginated_entities<'a, T>(
  &'a self,
  query: &'a TryStream<Ok = T::ResponseData, Error = anyhow::Error> + 'a
where
  T: PaginatedEntity
{
  try_unfold(StreamState::Start, async move |state| {
    // stream state handling code that defines `cursor`
    let data = query.get_data(self, cursor).await?
    // more data + state computations + return result of `get_data`.
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to define something like

```
struct SomeEntityQuery { filter: String }
impl PaginatedEntityQuery for SomeEntityQuery { /* … */ }
```

Finally, I can define a function that uses `get_paginated_entities` to do the heavy lifting:

```
fn get_some_entities(filter: String, /* … */) -> impl TryStream<Ok = Vec<SomeOtherType>, Error = anyhow::Error> + 'a {
  backend.get_paginated_entities(&SomeEntityQuery { filter }).map_ok /* … */
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work. I've defined an instance of `SomeEntityQuery` in `get_some_entities` but I'm returning owned values. Rust can't know that no parts of `SomeEntityQuery` actually show up in the return value.

I'd make `query: &'a T` in `get_some_entities` owned instead of a ref, but then I move `t` out in the `async move` that I give to `try_unfold` and since it's an `FnMut` that closure can't own it multiple times anyway. It has `query` has to be shared. Also, removing the ref form `T` gets Rust to complain about the type parameter potentially not living long enough.

Is there a way to make sure that values for the query itself aren't required to live as long as the values the query returns? Or possibly to extend the lifetimes of the query? I'm fine with copying the query a lot, if need be. It's lightweight, and performance is network bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first make a minimal working example of this that we can actually compile:

```rust
trait Query {
    fn get_data<'backend>(&self, backend: &'backend Backend) -> Result<'backend>;
}

struct Result<'data> {
    data: &'data str,
}

struct Backend {
    database_data: String,
}

struct SomeQuery {
    length_filter: usize,
}

impl Query for SomeQuery {
    fn get_data<'backend>(&self, backend: &'backend Backend) -> Result<'backend> {
        Result {
            // we use SomeQuery here, but it's not in the data
            data: &backend.database_data[..self.length_filter],
        }
    }
}

impl Backend {
    fn get_paginated_entities<'backend>(
        &'backend self,
        query: &'backend SomeQuery,
    ) -> Result<'backend> {
        query.get_data(self)
    }
}

fn get_some_entities<'backend>(
    length_filter: usize,
    backend: &'backend Backend,
) -> Result<'backend> {
    backend.get_paginated_entities(&SomeQuery { length_filter })
}
```

Hopefully now it's easier to find the problem; Rust thinks the data has the same lifetime as the query because we *told* it they do!

```rust
fn get_paginated_entities<'backend>(
    // the returned data is referenced from the backend,
    // so we specify a lifetime that Result lives as long
    // as backend does
    &'backend self,

    // but we told Rust here that query also has a lifetime
    // of 'backend, so the query also has to live as long as
    // the return value does
    query: &'backend SomeQuery,
) -> Result<'backend> {
    query.get_data(self)
}
```

We can use multiple lifetimes here to say that the lifetime of the return value doesn't have anything to do with the query lifetime (we don't actually need it in this example, but you would in your code).

```rust
fn get_paginated_entities<'backend, 'query>(
    &'backend self,
    // now the return data isn't linked to query's lifetime
    query: &'query SomeQuery,
) -> Result<'backend> {
    query.get_data(self)
}
```

This works fine because `get_data` also specifies that `query`'s lifetime isn't linked to `Result`.

```rust
fn get_data<'backend>(&self, backend: &'backend Backend) -> Result<'backend>;
```

EDIT: the problem here also has to do with `async`; since we don't know when the code will run, the data must be `'static`. We can fix this by using `Rc` instead of a normal reference. `Rc` effectively has a static lifetime since it can float around forever until there are no more references to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking my poorly asked question and answering it so nicely! That definitely helped expand my horizon with respect to lifetimes. I'll accept the answer, because wrt the question, it does a good job of answering it. Unfortunately, it seems that the types in my program are somewhat more complicated. I shall try to apply your advice and ask another question should it become necessary!

Comment: I think my problem stems from the fact that `get_data` doesn't return `Result<'backend>` but `Pin<Box<dyn Future… + 'backend>>`. So, as I see it, `Pin` is owned by `get_data`'s `self` lifetime? Which gives me: *lifetime mismatch*, as `query.get_data` in `paginated_entities` returns something in the lifetime of `query` and not just in the lifetime of the backend. But thanks, I'll try to see if I can remedy the situation.

Comment: @AleksandarDimitrov `async` lifetimes are indeed more complicated, and I'm unfortunately not familiar enough with `Future` to give a definitive answer especially without a minimal reproducible example. However, I think the issue is that `Future` is always bounded by the references it uses. Assuming `get_data` returns a future that uses `&self`, even if `&self` isn't in `ResponseData`, since `Future`s are lazy `&self` doesn't live long enough. See https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html#async-lifetimes

Comment: Can you try to change `&self` to `self: Rc<Self>` (of course refactoring the rest of your code accordingly)?  Using an `Rc` removes the lifetime bound on `self`. If that works I'll edit my answer.